# I prepare for situation of losing my cell phone

Tags: word-choice, grammar

To prepare for situation of losing my cell phone, I am making a sticker label for my cell phone.

Is this sentence okay?

> **"If you pick up this phone, please contact us. Tel: xxx-xxx-xxx"**

If it's not, please recommend a better sentence.

Comment: Contact 'me', unless there's more than one of you.

Answer (score 1):

I would replace 'pick up' with 'find'. And consider removing 'us' from the end of the sentence.

Comment: Yep, "If found, please call xxx-xxx-xxxx."